# Change timestamp in Google Sheets from when a Google Form is submited

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

When a Google Form is submitted, a timestamp is automatically inserted in column A. Is there a way to change the format of the timestamp, only need MM/dd/yyyy, and to change the column to B.

Couldn't find anything when looking for an option in Forms or Sheets involving automatic inserted timestamp

Comment: Discovered dragging the timestamp column to it's desired location works, who'd've thought 

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Go to Column A where the timestamp is and right click on it, then press Insert 1 column to the left.

You will be having another column in A and the timestamp will be submitted in B

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a formula instead of Apps Script, you can create a second sheet in the responses file, and pull the responses into it. QUERY will allow you to do this and rearrange the columns by using SELECT. For example, this code will swap columns A and B:

```
=QUERY(A1:B4, "SELECT B, A")
```

See [my example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hnoKogM7C0WmzKYXZXyMbaxPVb1j6aY4jtnklvf248U/edit#gid=0).

For the date format, you can just select the entire row that contains the dates (in the new sheet), and change the number format.
(Format > Number > [select your desired date format]